# Laravel 5- Foreach loop saves just last record?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to save my array data but when I tried with foreach loop, it saves just last records.

Here is form blade (without unneccesary html code) ;

```
@foreach($categories as $key=>$category)

  <input type="hidden"  name="menusettings[{{$key}}][menu_name]" value="{{$category->category_name}}">
  <input type="hidden"  name="menusettings[{{$key}}][menu_slug]" value="category/{{$category->category_slug}}" >
  <input type="checkbox" checked name="menusettings[{{$key}}][menu_status]">
  <input type="number" value="$i" name="menusettings[{{$key}}][menu_order]" >

@endforeach
```

And Controller; 
public function postUpdateMenu(Request $requests){

```
        $menu = new Menu;

                $request = $requests->get('menusettings');

                foreach ($request as $reques) {

                    $menu_status = isset($reques['menu_status']) ? 1 : 0;

                    $menu->menu_name = $reques['menu_name'];
                    $menu->menu_slug = $reques['menu_slug'];
                    $menu->menu_status = $menu_status;
                    $menu->menu_order = $reques['menu_order'];

                    $menu->save();
                }

    return back();


}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: put `$menu = new Menu;` inside the loop

Comment: that is because you put `$menu = new Menu` outside of your loop, that way, laravel create a menu item, then update it every loop

Comment: @Zoran and am05mhz thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. The code you are writing is not recommended.

Still if you want to go your way:
Try by replacing your code with the following:

```
            $request = $requests->get('menusettings');

            foreach ($request as $reques) {
                // every time the loop executes a new instance needs to be assigned.
                $menu = new Menu;
                $menu_status = isset($reques['menu_status']) ? 1 : 0;

                $menu->menu_name = $reques['menu_name'];
                $menu->menu_slug = $reques['menu_slug'];
                $menu->menu_status = $menu_status;
                $menu->menu_order = $reques['menu_order'];

                $menu->save();
            }

            return back();
```

**The method shown above is not at all recommended as every time the loop executes a connection is made to the database.**
Now lets consider the other option(Recommended as this is better.)
You will also need to declare the following array in your **Menu** model

```
protected $fillable = [ 'menu_name','menu_slug', 'menu_status','menu_order','created_at' , 'updated_at'];
```

*Controller Code:*

```
        $request = $requests->get('menusettings');
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //alternatively you may also use Carbon::now
        $menu = [];

        foreach ($request as $reques) {
            $menu_status = isset($reques['menu_status']) ? 1 : 0;

            $menu[] = [ 'menu_name' => $reques['menu_name'] , 'menu_slug' => $reques['menu_slug'] , 'menu_status' => $menu_status , 'menu_order' => $reques['menu_order'] , 'created_at' => $now , 'updated_at' => $now];
        }
        Menu::insert($menu);
        return back();
```

Comment: thanks, but @am05mhz alredy said that. But still I don't know, why do we define model in loop ?

Comment: What's wrong with connecting to the database each time it loops?  @oreopot

Comment: Less efficient as extra resources are being used when connecting to database multiple times where the exact could be achieved in more efficient way.